# Prove that the coordinate projection $P: E\times F\rightarrow E$ is an open map.

Tags: general-topology

I have a question on topology: how to prove that $P: E\times F\rightarrow E; P((x,y))=x$ is open

such that the first question is: $f:E\rightarrow F$ is open iff $\forall x\in E, \forall V\in \mathcal{V}_x. f(V)\in \mathcal{V}_{f(x)}$

I say let $(x,y)\in E$ and $V\in \mathcal{V}_{(x,y)}$ I have to prove that $P(V)\in \mathcal{V}_x$

But I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $V \in \mathcal{V}_{(x,y)}$ implies that there is an open set $O_x$ containing $x$ and an open set $O_y$ containing $y$ such that $O_x \times O_y \subseteq V$. This is the definition of the product topology, essentially.

Then $P(V)$ contains $O_x$ so you are done.

Comment: is P(O_x\times O_y)=P(O_x)?

Comment: $P(O_x \times O_y) = O_x$ as long as $O_y$ is non-empty (which it is). Hence $O_x \subseteq P(V)$.

Answer (score 0):

For $i\in \{1,2\}$ let $T_i$ be the topology on $E_i.\;$ The Tychonoff-product  topology $T_G$ on $G=E_1\times E_2$ is defined to be the weakest topology  on $G$ such that the projections $p_1, p_2$ of $G$ to $E_1, E_2$ are continuous. For continuity of $p_1,p_2$ to hold with respect to any topology $W$ on $G$, it is necessary and sufficient that $$\forall U\in T_1\;(U\times E_2\in W)\quad \land \quad \forall V\in T_2\;(E_1\times V_2\in W).$$ $$\text {Therefore}\quad   T_G \supset  B=\{U\times E_2: U\in T_1\}\cup \{E_1\times V: V\in  T_2\}.$$  Now $B$, above, is a sub-base for a topology $T^*$ on $G.\;$ And $T^*\subset T_G$ because $B\subset T_G$. And $T^*$ satisfies the conditions for continuity of $p_1,p_2$. Thus, the subset-minimality  of $T_G$ implies $T^*=T_G.\quad$  Now observe that if a function $f $ maps all members of a sub-base to open sets then $f$ is an open map. Applying this with $f\in \{p_1,p_2\}$ and with the sub-base $B$ for $T_G$, we are done.$\quad$$$.......$$ Remarks:  For any product-set  $P=\prod_{j\in J}E_j$ of topological spaces, the Tychonoff-product topology on $P$ is the weakest topology on $P$ that makes each projection $p_j:P\to E_j$ continuous. It has been very useful.